# What are some FS2 Error Hanlding Practices?

Tags: scala, cats-effect, fs2

I am new to FS2, Cats Effect, etc., but I have been using Scala since 2005 and Akka since 2010...

I tuned up the FS2 example code to play with error-handling ideas, but I wondered if there are better idiomatic ways to deal with this.

I tried the various Stream mechanisms, but, it was very troublesome, and the best I could do was collapse the whole stream into a single output value. I had a lot of trouble finding good documentation on error handling in FS2.

```
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}
import fs2.{Stream, text}
import fs2.io.file.{Files, Path}

import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object Converter extends IOApp.Simple {

  private val converter: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    def fahrenheitToCelsius(f: Double) =
      (f - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0)

    def convert(string: String) =
      try
        Success(fahrenheitToCelsius(string.toDouble).toString)
      catch
        case cause: Exception => Failure(cause)

    Files[IO].readUtf8Lines(Path("testdata/fahrenheit.txt"))
      .filter(s => s.trim.nonEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
      .map(line => convert(line) match 
        case Success(value) => value
        case Failure(cause) => s"Failed to convert $line: ${cause.getMessage}"
      )
      .intersperse("\n")
      .through(text.utf8.encode)
      .through(Files[IO].writeAll(Path("testdata/celsius.txt")))
  }

  def run: IO[Unit] =
    converter.compile.drain
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly would you like to do when you get an error? Skip the record? Log and slip? re-try the operation? Stop the whole stream? Start the whole process once again? Run an alternate process?

Comment: In the example given, my goal was to eat the error, and replace it with a string in the stream representing the error. So basically I am asking if I am doing this the best way, or is there a better, more idiomatic way?

Comment: Well there is no better or more idiomatic way. Error handling is probably one of the most subjective and context dependant topics. `Stream` allows you to do all that I said and more, including what you did. All of them are useful to some folks and in some specific contexts. Thus, my question is, what do you want to do? What you did is perfectly fine if what you wanted was to replace errors with _"valid values"_ (I would have used `toDoubleOption` and `Either` instead, but those are minor details). - Now, not sure if your end user wanted to see both success and errors in the same output file.

Comment: Yes, that is helpful. `toDoubleOption` helps. You are clearly more intelligent than GitHub Copilot ;-) Hunting through the IntelliJ alternate methods can lead to madness. There does not seem to exist `toDoubleEither` so I will have to play with that. I totally agree "Error handling is probably one of the most subjective and context dependant topics." It also seems to be one of the most ignored subjects as most people seem more interested in the *happy path* than robust reliability and diagnostics. Years ago, I played with Akka Streams, but PS2 seems a quantum leap better.

Comment: You can do `string.toDoubleOption.toRight(left = "SOME ERROR MESSAGE")` or maybe a custom exception if you prefer that.

Comment: Yes, but I want to capture the *cause* of the Exception...

Comment: If you want to, you may create your own `NmberFormatException` or whatever it is. I really have never ever cared about that exception, it just means the `str` is not a number.

Comment: I found what I wanted... see my answers...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Luis Miguel Mejia Suarez, I tweaked this to become

```
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}
import fs2.{Stream, text}
import fs2.io.file.{Files, Path}

object Converter extends IOApp.Simple {

  private val converter: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    def fahrenheitToCelsius(f: Double) =
      (f - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0)

    Files[IO].readUtf8Lines(Path("testdata/fahrenheit.txt"))
      .filter(s => s.trim.nonEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
      .map(line => line.toDoubleOption match
        case Some(value) => fahrenheitToCelsius(value).toString
        case None => s"Failed to convert $line to a number."
      )
      .intersperse("\n")
      .through(text.utf8.encode)
      .through(Files[IO].writeAll(Path("testdata/celsius.txt")))
  }

  def run: IO[Unit] =
    converter.compile.drain
}
```

If `toDoubleOption` did not exist, the right thing to do would have been to implement it. It might be worth implementing `toDoubleEither` or `toDoubleTry` as those do not seem to exist.

I had tried playing with `Stream` methods like `handleError`, `HandleErrorWith`, `evalTap`, `evalFilter`, etc., but I could not achieve what I wanted. I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

After more experimentation, I find the following more satisfying...

```
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}
import fs2.{Stream, text}
import fs2.io.file.{Files, Path}

import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object Converter extends IOApp.Simple {

  private val converter: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    def fahrenheitToCelsius(f: Double) =
      (f - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0)

    Files[IO].readUtf8Lines(Path("testdata/fahrenheit.txt"))
      .filter(s => s.trim.nonEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
      .map(line => Try {line.toDouble} match
        case Success(value) => fahrenheitToCelsius(value).toString
        case Failure(cause) => s"Failed to convert $line: $cause"
      )
      .intersperse("\n")
      .through(text.utf8.encode)
      .through(Files[IO].writeAll(Path("testdata/celsius.txt")))
  }

  def run: IO[Unit] =
    converter.compile.drain
}
```

Sometimes, I forget how powerful Scala is, even without Cats Effect and FS2...